# Building a class: building_dict() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am building a class that cleans out the raw data from scraping the Instagram comments and building them onto dictionary. The class should sequentially execute a number of functions that are all used in the very last `def building_dict()` one. However, I've faced the issue: `building_dict() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I've already tried to play around with moving the `.self` and `rawdata` in the `__init__`, yet it seems that I have the mistake hidden deeply in the code.

The rawdata I was using is simply that after preprocessing() being executed: test_1 = ['vit4017\nLike always\n16h2 likesReply'].

The result of the current code should be {id {'Username': _, 'Comment': _, 'Date_back': _, 'Likes': _}}

I feel stuck, thank you in advance.

```
    import re

class InstagramCleaning(object):
    def __init__(self, rawdata):
        self.rawdata = rawdata
        self.result = self.building_dict(rawdata)
        return result 

#Splitting the comment and removing the word "ответить"
    def preprocessing(rawdata):
        notSorted = [comment.text.split('Ответить') for comment in rawdata]
        allin = [word for comment in notSorted for word in comment]
        return allin

#Removing the user from the list (so we can work with the data in the comment) 
    def excluding_user(allin):
        rest = [rest for comment in allin for _, rest in [comment.split('\n', 1)]]
        return rest

#Getting dates out of the whole comment string 
    def filter_dates(rest):
        dates = []
        for date_back in rest:
            #for those posts that do not have any likes
            if bool(re.search(r"[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+Reply", date_back.rsplit('\n', 1)[1])) == True: 
                my_findings = re.search(r"[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+Reply", date_back.rsplit('\n', 1)[1])
                dates.append(my_findings.group().split('Reply',1)[0])
                # for those posts that do have likes 
                if date_back.split()[-1] in ('likesReply', 'likeReply'): 
                    dates.append(date_back.split()[-2][:-1])
        return dates
    #оставшиеся
#Getting likes out of the whole comment string 
    def filter_likes(rest):
        likes = [like.split()[-2][-1] if like.split()[-1] in ("likesReply",'likeReply') else 'None' for like in rest]
        return likes

    #Getting the username from the whole string

    def username(allin):
        username = [ user for comment in allin for user, _ in [comment.split('\n', 1)]]
        return username

    #оставшиеся
    #Getting the text of the comment out
    def comment_text(rest):
        comment_text = [comment.rsplit('\n', 1)[0] for comment in rest]
        return comment_text

    #Finally building dictionary
    def building_dict(self):
        allin = preprocessing(rawdata)
        rest = excluding_user(allin)
        dates = filter_dates(rest)
        likes = filter_likes(rest)
        username = username(allin)
        comment = comment_text(rest)
        all_data = list(zip(username, comment, dates, likes))
        dicts = {i: {'Username' : usernames_and_comments[i][0], 'Comment':  usernames_and_comments[i][1], 'Dates back': usernames_and_comments[i][2], 'Likes': usernames_and_comments[i][3]} for i in range(len(all_data)
) }
        return dicts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit I did not read through your entire codes. But if you want to refer to any attributes you assigned in `def __init__()` of `InstangramCleaning` in your `def building_dict` block, please use `self.your_attribute` instead of `your_attribute`. For example:

```
def building_dict(self):
    allin = preprocessing(self.rawdata)
```

In addition I would actually suggest reading a bit about the structure of a python class: [Python Classes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) might be helpful.